# Visual Studio Enterprise 2019/2022 - Change/Identify Code written in which programming Language

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Can anyone guide me how can someone identify/change the language of a file that has no extension in Visual Studio 2019/2022 ?

For example as in Notepad++, we navigate to language in the ribbon and select the language from there.

I try navigating to Tools and views to see the language button or anything related to that, but all in vain.

Not able to see the JS editor in this window.
[image]

Set JS Editor for Extensionless files. But JS syntax in file is not highlighting
[image]

Anyone ?

Comment: are you unable to give it an extension? I'm unsure if VS2022 allows you to select the language of a file which does not have an extension, however I'm fairly sure Visual Studio Code would.

Comment: @EgoPlacebo I am able to give it extension, but the need is, without giving the extension, I know which language it is. I can give the extension to it directly. But VS can do it ? this is the main requirement.

Comment: Right-click the file in the solution explorer choose the open-with option and pick the editor you want.

Comment: @jessehouwing
 yes. that solve the problem partially. but there are some default editors in it. I am not able to see the for JavaScript.
The problem will be resolve if i see JS editor in OPEN WITH window.
or I need something else in VS to open the file in JS editor.

Comment: @Muhammad even in Notepad++ you *don't* select the language unless the file has no extension. That's the extension, not the rule. It's there because shell files may have no extension. Notepad++ is a file editor used to edit multiple formats, not an IDE meant to *build, debug and edit* entire projects. Your main requirement is unclear and unusual

Comment: @Muhammad when you build your file or project in any language, you have to specify what files to include *somehow*. That somehow is most of the time through the extension (.go, .cpp, .js, .cs, .py). Otherwise your build tool would try to build or package your `README` file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Thanks for your point of view. 
But, i am not saying to build the project, in that, surely, we need to give the extension for success. I just want to edit the file directly in Visual Studio. the problem is in my mind, i know that's the JS file. but how VS know that it's JS ? I just want to open that file in JS editor in Visual Studio.

Comment: That doesn't exist. What you ask isn't "just", as you'll find when Notepad++ or VS Code mistakes JSON for Swift (happened yesterday). Automatic language detection may be added in the future but isn't a priority right now. VS is too heavy to be used as an editor. I'm not sure if even Rider offers automatic language detection

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio relies on the extension of a file to load the language plugins. You can configure which editors are available for which extensions in the Visual Studio settings:

[image: Set the editor for a specific extension]

You can set the default editor for extensionless files there, but that's far from ideal. You'll need to close and re-open the file for the editor change to take effect.

[image: Set Javascript as the default editor for extensionless files.]

I'm not aware of an extension that will allow you to change the editor (language) after a file has been opened.

You can select from a limited number of editors using the <kbd>open with...</kbd> option in the Solution Explorer:

[image: Open in a specific editor]

The list of editors there is limited though:

[image: List of available editors in Visual Studio]

Your best bet is "Source code editor".

A simple solution for your problem, and what I do in this case, is to add to "Open in Visual Studio Code" extension:

[image: Add the Open in Visual Studio Code extension]

Visual Studio code is much more geared towards a universal file editor instead of a solution editor:

[image: Jump to VsCode directly from Visual studio using the extension]

[image: Select the language parser for the file in Visual Studio code]

Comment: Thanks for the point of view, in VS 2022, i am not able to see the JS editor in Open With window. 
See the attached file in top.

Comment: I know, there's only a `Source Code (text)`  editor that will try to auto-detect the language.

Comment: with `Source Code (text)` the file contents are not getting changed. (colored function and code lines) Not detecting the JS.

Comment: Hence, why I use the "open in VSCode" option. The official answer is, if you set the default language for extensionless files to Javascript, it should do what you want, but for all extensionless files. Visual Studio depends on the extension to select the correct parser.

Comment: I have done this but the file syntax is not highlighting as JS. Not sure, how this will work. Screen shot is attached above.

Comment: In your solution, is the file type set to `content` or to `compile` or anything else?

Comment: It is `AssemblyInfo.cs` in .csproj file.
`<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: No, for the extensionless file...

Comment: For me, after setting the extensionless editor to "Javascript" and closing and re-opening the file in Visual Studio, I get syntax highlighting.

Comment: For me, the syntax highlight is not working after setting the extensionless editor to "Javascript" .